# How can I change dxdebug.remote_host before lunch PHP Script debug in PHPStrom?

Tags: php, debugging, ide, xdebug, phpstorm

I have **remote server** where I have **xdebug extension installed**, and it works perfectly with web application. But now I want to **debug console application**, and here I have a troubles.

**PHPStorm**

I am trying to set `-dxdebug.remote_host=***` in *debug configuration -> interpreter options*, but as I see in console window `-dxdebug.remote_host` is overridden with default value, and running local php interpreter.

But I need to run this console app with php configuration that is on my remote server.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration is to run/debug php script in CLI (console) mode on the SAME computer where IDE is running. You cannot launch CLI script on remote machine via this functionality.

Comment: As I understand you want to debug CLI-mode script that is running on remote machine (where you have xdebug installed), right?

Comment: @LazyOne, yes that is what I want.

Comment: @LazyOne I've tried PHP Remote Debug, but nothing happens when I click on green bug icon.

Comment: "PHP Remote Debug" is expecting HTTP initiation. For CLI mode you need to make some manual adjustments on REMOTE machine. Please refer to the link in my answer.

Comment: @LazyOne That's not true anymore. http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/04/php-remote-interpreters-support-in-phpstorm-8-eap/

Comment: @BrianGordon Yes, I'm perfectly aware of that -- my answer is soon to be 1 year old -- lots of changed since then (missing features got implemented). Q is: what's the point of your comment (such comment)?

Comment: @LazyOne Well, I have this exact question and it's legitimate now. I'm just noting for new readers that your comment is inaccurate for the latest version.

Comment: @BrianGordon Sure thing. You just should have done it (wording/addressing) in a better (neutral) way.

Answer (score 2):

"PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration (which you are trying to use) is to run/debug php script in CLI (console) mode on the **SAME** computer where IDE is running. You cannot launch CLI script on remote machine via this functionality, therefore providing your own `-dxdebug.remote_host=***` does not makes much sense here.

But yes -- you can debug remotely executed CLI scripts -- you just need to make some adjustments to xdebug as well as pass some special environment variables. Remote script needs to be launched manually though (not via Run/Debug configuration for sure -- maybe remote external tools may help here).

It's all described here:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-easier-debugging-of-remote-php-command-line-scripts/
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7906